# What screw to use to screw a piece of metal with an existing hole into wood that would normally be M6 size?

Tags: wood

I have a piece of equipment made in Japan that has a metal base which I would like to screw into a piece of plywood and place the whole thing on a table.  I was told the screw for the hole size in the metal is M6 (being from Japan they gave metric sizes).  The plywood is only 3/4” thick and I don’t think the sheet of metal is thick at all.  What imperial size wood screw can I use that would fit?  I don’t know the exact size of the metal hole yet.  But being a bit thinner and using a washer may be safer if that is the correct method.  What are my options?  I am a beginner at screws and handiwork in general.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is the hole threaded?

Comment: What appears to be a simple question is actually complicated. No one here wants to advise anything that could hurt someone. So in the interest of safety, please explain what the equipment will be used for. What it may weigh, dimensions, etc. and a pic or 2 so we may get this right.  Perhaps it should be bolted through the plywood. That may be overkill. We simply do not know with the information you provided. Please give us more.

Comment: I don’t think so.  Just a flat sheet of metal.

Comment: As far as I know the whole thing is about 15 lbs.  it will sit upright on a table.  I just don’t want it to move around.  It should be well balanced but may shift a little.    I have an inexpensive black and decker drill to drill a Pilot hole for the screw into the 3/4” plywood.     If you think it’s best to wait until I receive it to get a few screws, I will.

Comment: why exactly do you think you need imperial screws?  Metric screws are available everywhere.

Comment: I would use metric screws but they are usually not threaded to go into wood.  How would I work around this?  Say if I have a standard M6.  I don’t think a pilot hole is enough for the screw to dig into the wood.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: You'll have difficulty finding M6 **wood** screws (even McMaster-Carr only lists a few.) If you read the 3rd paragraph of my answer, that's how you use machine screws in wood.

Comment: Thanks I understand now.  If I want to try the M6 screw and perhaps corresponding tee nut, can I use a standard drill bit to drill the pilot hole for the M6?  Which bit would you suggest trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#12 round head, but good luck finding those in a 3/4" or less length.

However, #12 pan-head sheet metal screws work well in wood and you stand a better chance of finding those that short.

You will get a better/stronger connection using #12 machine screws and Tee nuts into the backside of the plywood, or M6 machine screws and Tee nuts. Metric fasteners are easily found at any half-decent hardware store, or online. The Tee nut grabs a lot more plywood than the threads of a screw directly into the plywood, and the metal threads of the Tee nut are much stronger than threads in wood.

[image: M6 Tee Nut image from AFTfasteners.com, no endorsement implied]

Carriage bolts (+ washer, lockwasher, and nut) are another good solution for connecting metal to wood. The carriage bolt head goes on the backside (you can drill a shallow recess if it needs to be completely flush) and the washer, lockwasher, and nut go on the side you are attaching your device to.

[image: Carraige bolt example picture from fastenersuperstore.com, no endorsement implied]

Comment: Thanks I understand this now.  For a M6 screw (and tee nut) can I use a standard drill bit to drill a pilot hole, and if yes, which size?  I don’t own a metric drill bit set right now.  Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Since Tee nuts are not very standardized, get your Tee nuts, and hold them up to the drill bits you have, since what you'll need is a hole that fits the outside of the central part with the threads.

Comment: It is between 7/32" and 1/4". There is a place called bolt depot that has the sizes and lengths you are interested in. I just checked stainless as that is what I use all the time. They would have the "T" nuts as well and you can purchase in quantities as small as 1.

Comment: 6mm is that. The barrel on a 6mm Tee nut (which is what you'll need a hole for) will be larger. Best to physically check it, as they are non-standardized (other than the threads internally) as already stated.